# How to read http header values in webservices (during Soap invoke())?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, http-headers, asmx

I have following method in a proxy class which will hit the service and give back response. How i can read http header informations on each invoke()? (on both request and response)

```
public ResponseRS MethodRqRs ([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="http://www.OTpAllia.com/2005/06")] RequestRQ requstRq)
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Action", new object[]{RequestRQ});
    return ((ResponseRS)(results[0]));
}
```

Comment: This appears to have been created with a web reference, or by using wsdl.exe. Is that correct? It makes a huge difference in the answer.

Comment: Yes, created by using wsdl.exe

Comment: Ok, were you aware that this is using the legacy ASMX web service technology, and that it should not be used for new development?

Comment: No, I am not aware of that. I am new to the web services development.So pardon me, if i asked any unrelated stuff. Is it possible to read http header on soap invoke? if yes means, Could please share any links that would help to understand  basics.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Now, what is your reason for wanting to read the headers, when do you want to read them, and what do you want to do with them?

Comment: Objective here is need to read the content-encoding field from the http header and based on the encoding, i need to decode the data.

Comment: I've never heard of this usage. Are you getting different encodings for different messages? Do you problems when you don't do this, or have you tried to not change encoding? What kind of service is this? In any case, you can't do this easily with a web reference. Use a service reference and you'll be able to override the message encoding.

Comment: Dynamically making decision over request to hit on different urls, where i am getting two different encoding from URLs. The same response but different encoding [Version upgrade].

Comment: Ok, but have you had an actual problem ? I would have expected even ASMX to handle different encodings.